# iOS 5 and iOS 6 - UIWebView difference in behaviour

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I am testing some HTML code on `UIWebView`.  And am also wishing to support both iOS 5.x and iOS 6.x.  But there seems to be a problem about font size associated with iOS 6.x only.

That is, under rotation, iOS 5.x would make fonts slightly smaller when changing to portrait from landscape mode (which is desirable, since portrait's width is shorter).  However, `UIWebView` in iOS 6.x would do just the opposite.

The problem does not come up when the same HTML code is rendered in iOS Safari (both 5.x and 6.x), as font size always scales as expected during rotation.

It could be something I've missed about `UIWebView`, hope somebody knowledgable could help to explain this.

Also, the above problem comes up on my iPhone 5 iOS 6.1 test device. Please comment if you do or don't find any similar problem. Wish to know if it is only associated with this particular phone (or its settings) only.

**Latest Update :**

The above problem should be related to how the project (which started long before iOS 6 was available) is laid out.  As have set up a new test project with a `UIWebView` and a `UIView` in some different basic setups, and the text autosizing during rotation seems to be ok in both ios 5 & 6. The above problem may be due to custom layout adjustment code used which is good only in iOS 5. Really wish there were more compatibility between the 2 ios versions.

Comment: Do you see any difference on the simulator?

Comment: please show us some code. how is the HTML viewport configured? how is the UIWebView configured?

Comment: Have tested both with and without viewport settings.  The viewport setting used is :  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;'>

Comment: With the above viewport setting, for iOS 6.x the font is smaller when loaded initially but becomes bigger when rotated the first time. Then the font would stays at the same bigger size after subsequence rotations. For iOS 5.x, the font stays at a constant size during all rotations which is expected.

Comment: The original setup when the question was posted has no viewport setting.  So font scalings mentioned were entirely UIWebView default behaviours.

Answer (score -1):

Please use the viewpoint setting to see the difference in ios 5 and ios 6