# UIWebView content is wider on iOS 5 than on iOS 6

Tags: ios, css, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a `UIWebView` containing some HTML where the containing `div`'s width and height are set to `100%`. This works great on iOS 6, where the div fills the `UIWebView` in both portrait and horizontal orientation. When I run it on iOS 5.1 it doesn't work. The `div`'s width seems to be `100%` of the iPad's screen instead of the `UIWebView`. The `UIWebView` enables the horizontal scrollbar and the content gets too wide.

What should I do to handle the needs of iOS 5 in this situation?

I have tried to insert some viewport options as mentioned in the comments of [iOS 5 and iOS 6 - UIWebView difference in behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933077/ios-5-and-ios-6-uiwebview-difference-in-behaviour), but it does not seem to make any difference.

Comment: Any clues? I face opposite problem! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579664

Answer (score 0):

I was always bothered by this pre-iOS-6 behavior, because as you say by default `UIWebView` uses the device's screen size, not the view view's frame. However adding the following `viewport` meta fixes the issue for me also on iOS 5. Try making sure to only load the content once the web view has its final frame.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```